# Is there a way to migrate the wi-fi configuration from one notebook to another?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, laptop, chromebook

I would like to find a way to migrate the wi-fi configuration from a notebook to another. I have already a working wifi configuration on the notebook A.

Let's say I want to export all the necessary files, drivers, profiles to the notebook B because I don't want to waste my time by configuring it again. The operating system on the notebook A is the same as on the B...it's Ubuntu 12.10, but kernel is not the same. The kernel on the notebook A is 3.5 and on B is 3.10.2. They are both Samsung ARM notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [article](http://juliusbeckmann.de/blog/ubuntu-backup-copy-network-settings-in-ubuntu.html), you would copy the following folders from one machine to another:

#### Network Settings

```
/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.gconf/system
```

#### Passwords

```
/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.gnome2/keyrings
```

Comment: Maybe this idea is good,but the problem here is bigger. The chromebook Kernel 3.10.2 actually does not support the wi-fi module....thanks anyway